# 2 functions onselect doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Trying to add 2 functions to onselect but it doesn't work.

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        var objDate = new Date(dateText);
        $('#checkinYear').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getFullYear() : '');
        $('#checkinMonth').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getMonth() + 1 : '');
        $('#checkinDay').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getDate() : '');
    }
    function (selectedDate) {
        $("#DepartureDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just slap an extra function definition wherever you want. If you want two functions to execute `onselect`, then you have to use **ONE** function to call your two functions:

```
onselect: function() {
     function1();
     function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect that to work?  There isn't even any kind of delimiter between the functions, there's no way for the syntax parser to "know what you mean" with that.

`onSelect` is expecting a function.  If that function needs to perform two operations, perform them both in the function:

```
onSelect: function (dateText) {
    var objDate = new Date(dateText);
    $('#checkinYear').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getFullYear() : '');
    $('#checkinMonth').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getMonth() + 1 : '');
    $('#checkinDay').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getDate() : '');

    $("#DepartureDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
}
```

If those functions are already defined elsewhere and need to be re-used, simply call them from within the anonymous function:

```
onSelect: function (dateText) {
    firstOperation(dateText);
    secondOperation(dateText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use it cant work. My advice will be to have a look at your design again and if this is something that needs to be done than you have to work on your syntax.

You may want to use anonymous functions. So if I take your example it should be something like

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
inline: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
minDate: 0,
onSelect: function (dateText) {
   function1(dateText);
   function2(selectedDate);  //Code to Populate selectedDate
}
});

var function1 = function(dateText){
      var objDate = new Date(dateText);
    $('#checkinYear').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getFullYear() : '');
    $('#checkinMonth').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getMonth() + 1 : '');
    $('#checkinDay').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getDate() : '');
}

var function2 =  function (selectedDate) {
    $("#DepartureDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}
```

Hope this may help.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: can you please share the code you used. It was a sample code to be used for reference. If you can let me have a look at the modified code may be I can help
Thanks :)

Comment: Oh.. it was for the reference :)